# Arabic text is not storing in the MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, character-encoding

I wish to find out why Arabic text is not storing in the databse. It changes to some other unicode format such as **%$&^%$%^&!**#***.

I'v made my column **Collation** as **utf8_general_ci**. Do I need to do some modification in my sql query?

My SQL query is:

```
$query="INSERT INTO blog_tab(blog_details) 
    VALUES('$blog_details') ";
```

Comment: change your collation to utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: are you using UTF8 character set?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Yes I am using UTF8 in database as Collation.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble : Thanks for the response. But its not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

The character set, collation and encoding seem to be correct.

Adding the following before connecting to the DB is supposed to help:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

The page at http://www.adviesenzo.nl/examples/php_mysql_charset_fix/ contains an explanation and further guidance for your issue.

Comment: I'll try it. Please be there. ll be back with my reponse. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysql_select_db('future');

$blog_details =$_POST['elm1'];
$query="INSERT INTO blog_tab(blog_details) 
  VALUES('$blog_details') ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "success";     I am trying something like this but its not working.  :( Please help me

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Have you set accept-charset="utf-8" ?  Did you read the link I posted?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the database, the SQL might be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `empid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

or like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `empid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB charset=latin1 ;
```

Try changing the `charset` to `utf-8` as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `empid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB charset=utf-8 ;
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Still it is not working. I changed the charset to utf-8 too. :(

Comment: If you use `phpMyAdmin`, try changing the `collation` with that... And after changing it, you need to again re-insert the data to be stored in `utf-8`, as the old data would have converted to `latin1` charset. Got it? Re-insert the data again and check if it is working. :)